# How to change text to input on click in Angular 5?

Tags: html, angular

I'm having trouble with setting values.
I need to make input instead of divs and set values instead of getting them when in "editMode".

```
                <div class="geim__sets">
              <div *ngFor="let set of game.sets" class="geim__set">
                <div *ngIf="set.get('tbrType') === 1 && !editMode" >
                  <div class="set1">{{ set.get('scoreFirst') }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="set1">{{ set.get('scoreSecond') }}</div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="set.get('tbrType') === 2 && !editMode">
                  <div class="set2">{{ set.get('scoreFirst') }}
                    <span class="power">{{ set.get('tbrFirst') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="set2">{{ set.get('scoreSecond') }}
                    <span class="power">{{ set.get('tbrSecond') }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="set.get('tbrType') === 3 && !editMode">
                  <div class="set3">[{{ set.get('scoreFirst') }}]</div>
                  <div class="set3">[{{ set.get('scoreSecond') }}]</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Currently it only gets values, but how do I change it on Click?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[(ngModel)]` ?? Something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="set?.tbrType === 1 && !editMode" >
      <input name="scoreFirst" [(ngModel)]=set?.scoreFirst>
      <input name="scoreSecond" [(ngModel)]=set?.scoreSecond>
 </ng-container>
```